# What's the proper way to pass url parameters to a react-router's Link component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So far I've been replacing the url params' values manually when using a link component, for example:

```js
const userIdParam = ':userId'

const routes = {
  userDetails: `/users/${userIdParam}`
}

<Link to={{
  pathname: routes.userDetails.replace(userIdParam, user.id)
}}/>
```

Does `react-router` support passing the params as props into the `to` object or something like this? I'm looking for something similar to the following:

```js
const routes = {
  userDetails: `/users/:userId`
}

<Link
  to={{
    pathname: routes.userDetails,
    props: {
      userId: user.id
    }
  }}
/>
```

I've been going through the typings and the docs but can't really find anything.

Answer (score 0):

> Does react router support passing the params as props into the `to`
> object or something like this?

Yes, sort of. You can use the [generatePath](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/generatePath) utility function to generate the `pathname` string.

The function takes a path pattern string and an object with properties that correspond to the path parameters.

Example:

```js
generatePath("/users/:userId", { userId: 123 }) // --> "/users/123"
```

```
import { Link, generatePath } from 'react-rotuer-dom';

...

const routes = {
  userDetails: "/users/:userId"
}

...

<Link to={generatePath(routes.userDetails, { userId: user.id })}>
  ...
</Link>
```